# Flume Custom Interceptor is not Working

Tags: flume

I want to change IP address in data by its mask IP. This is done in the "backup" part of my Flume agent (see below).

In this configuration there are 2 channels: the first channel dumps data to HBase, while the second one is used for backup:

```
a1.sources = r1 r2
a1.channels = channel1 Backup_channel
a1.sinks = FSink

a1.sources.r1.handler = com.flume.handler.JSONHandler
a1.sources.r1.type = avro
a1.sources.r1.bind = x.x.x.x
a1.sources.r1.port = 10008

a1.sources.r2.handler = com.flume.handler.JSONHandler
a1.sources.r2.type = avro
a1.sources.r2.bind = x.x.x.x
a1.sources.r2.port = 10009
a1.sources.r2.interceptors = i1
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.i1.type = com.flume.interceptor.DcInterceptor

a1.channels.channel1.type = file
a1.channels.channel1.checkpointDir = /root/flume/channels/Livechannel/checkpoint
a1.channels.channel1.dataDirs = /root/flume/channels/Livechannel/data

a1.sinks.FSink.type = hbase
a1.sinks.FSink.table = Temp_Test
a1.sinks.FSink.batchSize = 300
a1.sinks.FSink.columnFamily = T
a1.sinks.FSink.serializer = com.flume.sink.TestTP

a1.sources.r1.channels = channel1 
a1.sources.r2.channels = Backup_channel

a1.channels.Backup_channel.type = file
a1.channels.Backup_channel.checkpointDir = /data/disk/flume/backup/checkpoint
a1.channels.Backup_channel.dataDirs = /data/disk/flume/backup/data

a1.sinks.FSink.channel = channel1
```

Following is my custom Java Interceptor Code. It implements the interception method, which get an IP address from the body, calculates its IP mask and then adds it to the body. But somehow it's not working:

```
public class DcInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private byte[] jsonTestBeans;

    private final Type listType = new TypeToken < List < TestBeans >> () {}.getType();

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Logger();
    }

    @Override
    public Event intercept(Event event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List < Row > actions = new ArrayList < Row > ();
        this.jsonTestBeans = event.getBody();
        Logger.logger.debug("In Interceptor");
        System.out.println("In Interceptor");
        Gson _Gson = new Gson();
        String jsonstr = "";
        try {
            jsonstr = new String(jsonTestBeans, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Logger.logger.error(e.getMessage() + "In Interceptor");
            jsonstr = new String(jsonTestBeans);
        }
        List < TestBeans > TestBeanss = _Gson.fromJson(jsonstr, listType);
        System.out.println("Json String :" + jsonstr);
        List < String > gTouch = new ArrayList < String > ();
        for (TestBeans TestBeans: TestBeanss) {
            String str = TestBeans.getIp();
            Logger.logger.debug("IP  : " + str);
            String st = (str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + "x");
            Logger.logger.debug("Mask IP  : " + st);
            TestBeans.setRemoteIp(st);
        }
        event.setBody(_Gson.toJson(TestBeanss).getBytes());
        Logger.logger.debug("Interceptor Ends");
        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public List < Event > intercept(List < Event > events) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In List Interceptor");
        Logger.logger.debug("In List Interceptor");
        for (Event event: events) {
            intercept(event);
        }
        return events;
    }

    public static class CounterInterceptorBuilder implements Interceptor.Builder {

        private Context ctx;

        @Override
        public Interceptor build() {
            Logger.logger.debug("In Interceptor Build");
            System.out.println("In Build Interceptor");
            return new DcInterceptor();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(Context context) {
            this.ctx = context;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At least, I can see:

- The configuration lines regarding your interceptor refer to an agent called `ECircleTp_Test`, while the rest of the configuration refer to `a1`.
- You have configured `com.flume.interceptor.DcInterceptor2`, but the interceptor class you have developed is called `DcInterceptor` (without the final `2`).
- You have configured `com.flume.interceptor.DcInterceptor2` as the fully qualified class name of your custom interceptor. Nevertheless, the code of the interceptor does not declare any package for the `DcInterceptor(2)` class.

Comment: It's a typing mistake now it's perfect. can u plz check again #frb  Thanks

Comment: Nice. So, try adding to the interceptor `package com.flume.interceptor;` to the begining of the file.

Comment: If still failing, please add releveant logs to your question.

Comment: Thanks for prompt Rply. 'package com.flume.interceptor' is added in my code. I didn't find any relevaent log #frb

Comment: Main thing is backup channel is for the backup and i don't want to store full ip so i want that last digit of ip should be **X** . So when in future if i want to restore that data than that should be with mask ip not with full ip. but some how it's not working for me .